# Nodejs socketio listening on a specific room only

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to send an admin notification to all viewers. When an admin connects I join('admin') and I want to listen on that room for notification messages and pass them on to all users. This works, however I did a test from the users side and found I could still send messages as if I was an admin!?

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    connect = require('connect'),
    cookieParser = express.cookieParser('fwefwefvccc'),
    sessionStore = new connect.middleware.session.MemoryStore();


app.configure(function () {
    app.use(cookieParser);
    app.use(express.session({ store: sessionStore }));
});

var server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    sessionSockets = require('session.socket.io'),
    sessions = new sessionSockets(io, sessionStore, cookieParser);

sessions.on('connection', function (err, socket, session) {

    // Client functions trimmed for SO

    socket.on('adminJoin', function(data) { 

        if(data.password == "testing") {
            socket.join('admin');
        }
    }
    socket.in('admin').on('notification', function (data) {

        io.sockets.emit("notification", {
            'type': data.type,
            'msg': data.msg
        });
    });
});
```

It appears to ignore the fact the user isn't in the /admin/ room

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly what you want to do, but given the time with no reply I think this "workaround" would do the trick.

Please be aware that this is untested code :)

When an admin joins, let the socket know it is an admin.

```
socket.on('adminJoin', function(data) { 
    if(data.password == "testing") {
        socket.set("isadmin",true);
    }
}
```

And when a socket gets a message, check if the socket is admin.

```
socket.on("message,function(){
 if(socket.get("isadmin") == true)
 {
  io.sockets.emit("notification","Somethign happende")
 }

})
```